# How to write simple script in batch to run some cmd's?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am writing Server-Client program Java.

To test this program, I need to run several cmd windows. And this is very boring, especially if you just start work. The program operates in three sub-programs:

- Server
- Customer
- Server employee.

So I would like to write a script (I don't know how to do it because I've never written anything in batch) that:

- launches one cmd window in the directory e.g. **E:\java\myapp\**

  -will call the command: **java -cp (myJAR) app.Server**
- will run two cmd windows in: **E:\java\myapp\**

  -call the command: **java -cp (myJAR) app.Node**
- and finally launch one client window: **E:\java\myapp\**

  -call the command: **java -cp (myJAR) app.Client**

Comment: read about the [start](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) command and it's options.

Comment: `start` command does not help, Stephan. You haven't noticed that that the user said to start two "cmd windows" on specific directories.

Comment: Are you sure about that @WasifHasan, I have provided examples using `Start` in an answer. The benefit is that all three windows open up at the same time, _they don't have to wait for the previous one to complete_. I also think that the working directory and individual titles can be assigned more easily using `start`, _which also benefits from other options too! _(to see those options, other than the link in Stephan's comment, the OP can open a Command Prompt window and enter `start /?`)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
@Echo Off
cmd /k "pushd E:\Java\MyApp & java -cp (myJAR) app.Server"
cmd /k "pushd E:\Java\MyApp & java -cp (myJAR) app.Node"
cmd /k "pushd E:\Java\MyApp & java -cp (myJAR) app.Client"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the `Start` command, as advised in the comments:

```bat
@Start "Customer" /D "E:\Java\MyApp" Cmd /K "java -cp (myJAR) app.Client"
@Start "Employee" /D "E:\Java\MyApp" Cmd /K "java -cp (myJAR) app.Node"
@Start "Server" /D "E:\Java\MyApp" Cmd /K "java -cp (myJAR) app.Server"
```

You could also, if the working directory is the same for each use this alternative:

```bat
@PushD "E:\Java\MyApp" 2>NUL && (
    Start "Customer" Cmd /K "java -cp (myJAR) app.Client"
    Start "Employee" Cmd /K "java -cp (myJAR) app.Node"
    Start "Server" Cmd /K "java -cp (myJAR) app.Server"
    PopD)
```

Or this:

```bat
@CD /D "E:\Java\MyApp" 2>NUL || Exit /B
@Start "Customer" Cmd /K "java -cp (myJAR) app.Client"
@Start "Employee" Cmd /K "java -cp (myJAR) app.Node"
@Start "Server" Cmd /K "java -cp (myJAR) app.Server"
```

Another alternative, if the intention is to ensure that the ClassPath search includes `E:\Java\MyApp` or `E:\Java\MyApp\myJAR.jar` is to add it directly to the commands:

```bat
@Start "Customer" Cmd /K "java -cp E:\Java\MyApp\myJAR.jar app.Client"
@Start "Employee" Cmd /K "java -cp E:\Java\MyApp\myJAR.jar app.Node"
@Start "Server" Cmd /K "java -cp E:\Java\MyApp\myJAR.jar app.Server"
```

As also advised in the comments, to read the help and usage information for the `Start` and `Cmd` commands, open a Command Prompt window and enter `start /?` and `cmd /?` respectively.